# Why aren't all the screen fields available on Contract-based REST web services endpoints

Tags: acumatica

I've successfully created C# REST web service code to update a Project record (screen ID: PM301000) - but I've noticed not all the fields on the screen show up in the default endpoint list for Project.

Specifically -

Header:
Template, Entity Type

ProjectProperties:
Currency Rate Type

Plus, I can't seem to find anything that's in the "Project Address" group.  Do these exist somewhere else in the endpoint listings?   There just seem to be many groups / fields for the Project screen that aren't in the endpoint listings.  What am I missing?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to extend the endpoint to add those fields:

[image]

[image]

[image]

After performing these steps you can add any field on the screen to the endpoint

Comment: Thanks, Kyle.  Seems odd though - I always thought extending endpoints was for customizations (user fields, BLC extensions, etc.).

Comment: It certainly is! but not all base fields are returned as you can see